# foreachloop within a foreachloop MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I will try to explain it with more details.

In the database are the following manufacturers:
Apple, Canon, HTC, Hewlett, Palm and Sony.

This is the existing PHP-Code:

```
$query = $db->result_cache("
  SELECT   DISTINCT(SUBSTRING(manufacturers_name,1,1)) AS firstletter
  FROM     " . TABLE_MANUFACTURERS . "
  ORDER BY firstletter
");
$module_index = array();
$module_content = array();
foreach ($query['RESULT'] as $result) {
  $module_index[] = array(
    'MANU_INDEX' => $result['firstletter'],
  );
  $query = $db->result_cache("
    SELECT   manufacturers_name, 
             manufacturers_id 
    FROM     " . TABLE_MANUFACTURERS . "
    WHERE    manufacturers_name LIKE '" . $result['firstletter'] ."%'
    ORDER BY manufacturers_name
  ");
  foreach ($query['RESULT'] as $result) {
    if (SEARCH_ENGINE_FRIENDLY_URLS == 'true') {
      $SEF_parameter = '&name=' . inc_cleanName($result['manufacturers_name']);
    }
    $module_content[] = array(
      'MANU_NAME'  => $result['manufacturers_name'],
      'MANU_LINK'  => inc_url(FILENAME_DEFAULT, 'manufacturers_id=' . $result['manufacturers_id'] . $SEF_parameter),
    );
  } 
}
```

With the first mysql-query I fetch the first letter with a distinct to avoid double results (e.g. "H" because of HTC and Hewlett)

This is the array I get

```
Array(
[0] => Array([MANU_INDEX] => A)
[1] => Array([MANU_INDEX] => C)
[2] => Array([MANU_INDEX] => H)
[3] => Array([MANU_INDEX] => P)
[4] => Array([MANU_INDEX] => S)
)
```

and this is correct.

With the secound mysql-query I try to get all the manufacturers beginning with the first letter (e.g. "A" for Apple). But I always get all the manufacturers when I debug the $module_content array

```
Array(
  [0] => Array(
     [MANU_NAME] => Apple
     [MANU_LINK] => manufacturers_id=1)
  [1] => Array(
     [MANU_NAME] => Canon
     [MANU_LINK] => manufacturers_id=2)
  [2] => Array(
      [MANU_NAME] => Hewlett-Packard
      [MANU_LINK] => manufacturers_id=4)
  [3] => Array(
      [MANU_NAME] => HTC
      [MANU_LINK] => manufacturers_id=3)
  [4] => Array(
      [MANU_NAME] => Palm
      [MANU_LINK] => manufacturers_id=5)
  [5] => Array(
      [MANU_NAME] => Sony
      [MANU_LINK] => manufacturers_id=6)
  )
```

I don't understand the problem because the WHERE-clause in the second mysql-query says to fetch all the manufacturers with the beginning of the first letter.

Comment: Could you not just do a single query with `GROUP BY SUBSTRING(manufacturers_name,1,1)` ?

Comment: If I have two manufacturers with the letter "H" (like: HTC, Hewlett) it only shows one of them. So it doesn't work with a single query

Comment: If you want all the manufacturers what's the point of the first letter filter, just select all of them (no where clause). You can get the first letter with php, or another select field

Comment: I tried this an this works fine. But now I have to times the letter "H" in my manufacturers index because they are two manufacturers with the beginning of "H".

Comment: Sorry, what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: explain your question more please

Comment: I tried to refine my answer below

Comment: I thing it has something to with unset() the array.